# Grunt convert indentation to spaces

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, indentation

Is there a grunt task to convert all file indetations from tabs to spaces? I've tried to looking but the ones I found only lint the files or just don't work well. These are the ones I've tried:

- https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-indent
- https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-leading-indent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled upon the exact same problem as you, as I had a project with mixed indentation (1 tab, 4 spaces and 2 spaces). I ended up modifying grunt-indent to change from any style of indentation to the desired one (e.g. it converted all files to use 2 spaces).

`npm install grunt-fixindent --save-dev`
https://github.com/anton164/grunt-fixindent

Answer (score 1):

You may use [github.com/jonschlinkert/grunt-prettify](http://github.com/jonschlinkert/grunt-prettify) — I tested that plugin when I used `GruntJS`, so I know that it works fine).

the option you are looking for is `indent_char`

> **Type**: String Default value: ' ' (space)
>     **Options**: space|tab (use an actual space or tab, not the word)
>     Character with which to indent the output HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Try this grunt task.
This converts all files in directories recursively.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-convert-indent

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however nowadays JSCS is probably the way to go. https://www.npmjs.com/package/jscs